# How to switch model iterator between train and validate datasets?

Tags: tensorflow, iterator, tensorflow-datasets

I'm learning TensorFlow "lower API", where you manually specify layers using `tf.layers`, create datasets and iterators, and run the loops to train and validate the model. I am trying to run training and validation. Unfortunately, I am running into errors when trying to switch between training and validation datasets:

Here's what I have:

```
self.train_it = \
    train_dataset.batch(self.batch_size).make_initializable_iterator()
self.validate_it = \
    train_dataset.batch(self.batch_size).make_initializable_iterator()

...

input_layer = self.train_it.get_next()[0]
hidden1 = tf.layers.dense(
    input_layer,
    ... )

...

with tf.name_scope('train'):
  self.train_op = \
        tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(self.loss)

...

for epo in range(epochs):
  # Train using self.train_it iterator.
  self.sess.run(self.train_it.initializer)
  total_loss = 0
  for iteration in range(n_batches):
    summary, _, batch_loss = self.sess.run([self.merged_summary, \
        self.train_op, self.loss])
    total_loss += batch_loss
  print('   Epoch : {}/{}, Training loss = {:.4f}'. \
            format(epo+1, epochs, total_loss / n_batches))
  # Validate using self.valid_it iterator.
  self.sess.run(self.validate_it.initializer)
  # HOW DO I TELL THE MODEL TO USE self.valid_it INSTEAD OF self.train_it ???
```

The problem here is that in the beginning I already told the model to use `train_it` : `input_layer = self.train_it.get_next()[0]` , and now I have to tell it to switch between `train_it` and `validate_it` every epoch. I must be missing something in the API on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use reinitializable iterator and do the following.

```
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size_train)
val_dataset = validation_dataset.batch(batch_size_val)

iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(train_dataset.output_types, train_dataset.output_shapes)

train_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(train_dataset)
val_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(val_dataset)

data, labels = iterator.get_next()
```

Then link the data and the labels in the model. Afterwards while training do the following:

```
for e in range(epochs):
    sess.run(train_init_op)
    for iteration in range(n_batches_val):
        ....
    sess.run(val_init_op)
    for iteration in range(n_batches_val):
        ....
```

Let me know if you find something confusing.